# How to access stronglooop loopback application which is running on a subfolder on live server

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have installed strongloop loopback application on a live server on domain e.g: www.abc.com . I have created stronglooop loopback project in a subfolder called "lb" After successfull creation I executed the command "slc run" the terminal logs that your loopback app is running on http://localhost:3000 but when I opened www.abc.com/lb or www.abc.com:3000/lb... it was not running there ... What mistake I did? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loopback running on same domain but on another port so you can access it by http://www.example.com:3000

It's doesn't matter which folder your application is stored. When you run it, by default it runs on default domain on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy your app to that server using the command:

```
$ slc deploy http://user:pass@prod1.example.com:3000
```

This is also documented [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/slc+deploy)